# How do I filter or output within an array if the number I searched for was not found?

Tags: c++, c++11

I cannot output correctly when the number is not found in the array. I've tried multiple conditionals so it would only trigger when it is true. But nothing worked.

```
int main()
{
    int abfrage;

    cout << "Type a number between 0 and 1000 to find it's position in the array " << endl;
    cin >> abfrage;
    const int feld = 1001;
    int zahlenfeld[feld];
    int i = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < feld; i++)
    {
        zahlenfeld[i] = rand() % 1001;

        if (zahlenfeld[i] == abfrage)
        {
            cout << "Your number" << abfrage << " " << "is at the position" << i << endl;
        }
        else if (cin.fail() || abfrage > 1000 || abfrage < 0)
        {
            cout << "Wrong input. Only positive integers are possible." << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (zahlenfeld[i] != abfrage)
        {
            cout << "The number you searched for is not in the array." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you continueing the loop `if (zahlenfeld[i] == abfrage)` but `break`ing out of it if `if (zahlenfeld[i] != abfrage)`? And why are you checking for `if (zahlenfeld[i] != abfrage)` in the `else` of `if (zahlenfeld[i] == abfrage)`? You'll only know that the value was not in the array when you are at the end of the array, not at any other `i` in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have incorrectly combined two `for` loops. Currently, you set `zahlenfeld[i]` to a random number immediately before comparing it with `abfrage`.

You probably also want to allow the user to continue guessing until they choose a number that is in the array. So you can use a `while` loop to accept input multiple times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < feld; i++)
{
    // 1. Initialize array with random numbers
    zahlenfeld[i] = rand() % 1001;

    // 2. Check `zahlenfeld[i] == abfrage` ...
}
```

Should be

```
// 1. Initialize array with random numbers
for (int i = 0; i < feld; i++)
{
    zahlenfeld[i] = rand() % 1001;
}

while (true)
{
    cout << "Type a number between 0 and 1000 to find it's position in the array " << endl;
    cin >> abfrage;

    // 2. Check whether the guess appears anywhere in the array
    auto it = std::find(std::begin(zahlenfeld), std::end(zahlenfeld), abfrage);
    if (it != std::end(zahlenfeld))
    {
        cout << "Your number" << abfrage << " " << "is at the position" << (it - std::begin(zahlenfeld)) << endl;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The number you searched for is not in the array. Try again." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that makes much more sense thank you!. Didn't know about the find and end function either.